# Constructor in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller `constructori` that contains a constructor and a method `aas`.
I created a new object `$col = new constructori()`, and after that I call the method 
`echo $col->aas();`

```
Class Constructori  {

    function index(){

    }

    public function __construct(){

        echo" something <br />";
    }

    function aas(){
        echo 'another something <br>';
    }



}

$col = new Constructori();

echo $col->aas();
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting:

```
something

another something

something
```

instead of

```
something

something

another something
```

Comment: I suppose the framework (ci) is already instantiating the controller. I would expect the output to be ```s, s, a``` though

Comment: i know. The second and the third line of the output is confusing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is expected.  It first executes:

```
$col = new Constructori();//something
echo $col->aas();//another something
//Now codeigniter itself try to create new controller ---thats why you got something
```

The reason is Codeigniter loads all class first. Then creates its necessary classes object. So when it was loading class `Constructori` your code executes first. At last Codeigniter itself creates `Constructori` object.

Suppose your code is like this:

```
$col = new Constructori();
echo $col->aas();

$col2 = new Constructori();
echo $col2->aas();
```

Output will be:

```
  something        //for $col construct
  another something  //for $col->aas();

  something  //for $col2 construct
  another something // $col2->aas();

  something //last Codeigniter creates one
```

Comment: Good to know, I was under the impression the order of execution was the other way around.

Comment: Thank you! I thought codeigniter creates one  first and after that the rest of the code is executed.

Comment: Actually class should be loaded before creating object.So when codeigniter trying to load the class it also executes your others code too.